# Making custom close and minimize button

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I have a decorated `JFrame`. I need to make close button and minimize button. What should I do?

Here is my code snippet:

```
public Startup()
{
    setTitle("STARTUP");
    setSize(800,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: *"making custom close and minimize button"*  Why 'custom?  Note that once a window is undecorated, we can put anything we like inside it, what exact problems are you having with implementing the desired functionality?  Also: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: I need to add "X" as a close button and "-" as minimize button in that jframe.

Comment: Nothing happening after inserting setResizable(false);

Comment: public Startup1()
    {
        setTitle("STARTUP");
        setSize(800,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true); }

Comment: Can you read code in comments?  I, and most people, can't..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is very unique and will look quite good. There are many ways to solve your problem. Now, as per your request, you want a <kbd>CLOSE</kbd> and a <kbd>MINIMIZE</kbd> button. Let us make the following [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)s.

```
private final Action exitAction = new AbstractAction("Exit")
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };
private final Action minimizeAction = new AbstractAction("Minimize")
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
        }
    };
```

Now, let us apply the above actions to `JButton`s:

```
JButton closeButton = new JButton(exitAction);
JButton miniButton = new JButton(minimizeAction);
```

There you have it. Now, all you need to do is add your buttons to your `JFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

**Note For Eclipse Users**
this code will come in your minimize button when You click On minimize button in Eclipse.

`YourFrameName`  is  the Frame name you had set or it is set by default, use that frame name here:

```
YourFrameName.setState(YourFrameName.ICONIFIED);
```